# URL Waze (GPS), directing from browser to app

Tags: android, ios, url, redirect, waze

I have an Waze URL with the adresses settled in a button in an Web Page, in which souldnt calculate the route, only mark the pin at the map. This link should redirect the user to the Waze app, but waze is trying to trace a route to the given address, and it is not working when opening the app because it cant calculate the route.

Here´s the link im using for:
[https://www.waze.com/pt-BR/livemap?ll=-47.91084051%2c-15.83598078&%3bnavigate=yes&%3bzoom=17&lat=-15.8353442&lng=-47.9113094&zoom=16](https://www.waze.com/pt-BR/livemap?ll=-47.91084051%2C-15.83598078&%3Bnavigate=yes&%3Bzoom=17&lat=-15.8353442&lng=-47.9113094&zoom=16)

Is there any solve to this problem, or maybe another cause for it?

Answer (score 0):

Waze has recently reworked that part of the website, including the livemap. It would appear to me that it is indeed not possible to have the app not start the navigation straight away with what Waze calls [the deep links](https://developers.google.com/waze/deeplinks/). Even when setting `navigate` to `no`, it starts the navigation in the app.

I only know of a solution if you are certain that the user will not open this link on a desktop computer (as they'll get a blank screen) AND that the user has the Waze app installed on their phone.

When you look at the page you get on your mobile device if you follow the link you posted, you can see that the URL for that button to open the app uses the `waze://` syntax and ends with `n=T`. If you want the app to just show the location, you can set that n property to false like so: `n=F`. This gives something like `waze://?ll=-47.91084051,-15.83598078&n=F` for your example. You can just put that in the `<a>` tag like any other URL and it will work fine on a mobile device that has Waze installed. It'll do nothing (except maybe open a blank screen) on any other device though.

There is also an alternative URL syntax that just opens up the location without starting the navigation: `http://waze.to//?ll=<coords>`, but that one doesn't appear in the documentation and has the same effect as the `waze://` syntax, so I'd advice against using it.

You may also want to consider posting about these issues in [the announcement topic at the Waze forums](https://www.waze.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1913&t=271812) as they could use such feedback. I'll go ahead and make a remark about the `navigate=no` being ignored in that topic for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you directly want to open the Waze you can read the below link:

https://developers.google.com/waze/deeplinks#navigate-to-location
overall waze deeplink should be something like this format:

```
https://www.waze.com/ul?ll=35.699636,51.337608&navigate=yes&zoom=17
```

Otherwise, if you want to open all navigation apps list and select an application using the below format:

```
geo:0,0?q=35.699636,51.337608
```